# reledmac / reledpar lemma content size adjustment

Tags: footnotes, reledmac, reledpar

I am using reledmac / reledpar and would like to adjust the content of the lemma size so that it matches the size of the rest of each critical note. In the preamble, I am defining the following macro in the preamble:

\newcommandx{\edc}[2][1,usedefault]{\Bfootnote[#1]{\scriptsize#2}}

if I simply write

\newcommandx{\edc}[2][1,usedefault]{\Bfootnote[\scriptsize#1]{\scriptsize#2}}

the file does not compile. I am probably missing something rather basic. Thank you for your help. Kindly,

Jigdrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, the size of the lemma is the same as the size of the critical notes.

As explained in § 7.6.3 of the current handbook, you can use `\Xnotefontsize` to set it.
For example:

```
\Xnotefontsize[B]{\scriptsize}
```

For series B only

or

```
\Xnotefontsize{\scriptsize}
```

For all series.

Ps: as explained on § 6.2.2, the optional argument of a critical footnote must one (or more) of the following optiom:
- fulllines
- nonum
- nosep
- linerangesep

In any case, a command should be problematic, and won't have any effect.